# Import jcomment data to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, migrate

I want to migrate from Joomla to Wordpress and my comment handler extension in Joomla is jcomment.

How can I import whole comment's data from jcomment to wordpress database?

Here is the one of the post I found: 
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-joomlamambo-to-wordpress-migrator-migrate-comments#post-1990303
but I don't have any idea about its usage :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I fully understand your question, but I am going to try to help here. Have you looked at suggested methods on [wordpress migration page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#Joomla)? I dont have experience with jcomment but I think if it is only the post and comment data that you want to import, it should be straight forward. You can import your data to wordpress, but not its presentation, for good reasons. But if you want to carry plugin specific data, such as ratings, you need to first have an equivalent plugin on your wordpress site to understand that data. I suggest you search through [wordpress plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/) and choose a plugin that can replace jcomment for you. After that you need to do some research and see if there are any scripts avaiable that would handle the conversion and importing of the plugin specific data. Alternatively, you can write your own script to copy your data into wordpress database. Of course, assuming that you have access to the database.